# Why use gRPC for inter microservice communication?

Tags: node.js, microservices, grpc

I am learning `gRPC` implementing things with `node.js`. I read that `gRPC` and inter microservice communication goes well together.

What is the problem that gRPC solves that REST couldn't in context of inter microservice communication?

Why to use gRPC for inter microservice communication?

Comment: I'm at least glad to see that they include error handling and is asynchronous by default. In the past the failure of RPC was to treat network communications as a function call. It looks nice in theory but if you pull the ethernet plug or try your program on a slow mobile phone it breaks the illusion of the function call causes issues in your app. At least with REST we are explicitly aware that we are making a network request and all the errors that may pop up. IMHO the only advantage is gRPC makes it easier to write a client and server.. in languages like C++ and Java.

Comment: ... in javascript their API is as easy to use as Express so zero advantage from my point of view and their client API is less easy to use as `fetch()` so a minor disadvantage to me

Comment: The only likely advantage over REST (which would typically entail JSON) from a JS/python perspective is likely to be the enforced schema.  The HTTP/2 + protobuf combination might also perform better.

Comment: Yes, I see only these advantages, with gRPC you leverage power of HTTP2. Many request can be initiated within a single http connection. You can now stream the response. Overall a bit performance gain. But, We have to share the schema for a single byte of string. If there is a change, we have to update all the shared schema in all the services. _correct if I am wrong?_

Answer (score 0):

GRPC has following benefits
Lightweight messages. Depending on the type of call, gRPC-specific messages can be up to 30 percent smaller in size than JSON messages.

High performance. By different evaluations, gRPC is 5, 7, and even 8 times faster than REST+JSON communication.

Built-in code generation. gRPC has automated code generation in different programming languages including Java, C++, Python, Go, Dart, Objective-C, Ruby, and more.

More connection options. While REST focuses on request-response architecture, gRPC provides support for data streaming with event-driven architectures: server-side streaming, client-side streaming, and bidirectional streaming.

Answer (score 0):

gRpc had the following benefits over old Rpc.

- gRPC offers a refreshed take on the old RPC design method by making
  it interoperable, modern, and efficient using such technologies as
  Protocol Buffers and HTTP/2.
  The following benefits make it a solid candidate for replacing REST in some operations.
  Lightweight messages. Depending on the type of call, gRPC-specific messages can
  be up to 30 percent smaller in size than JSON messages.

  High performance. By different evaluations, gRPC is faster than
  REST+JSON  communication.

  Built-in code generation. gRPC has automated code generation in
  different programming languages including Java, C++,Python, Go, Dart,
  Objective-C, Ruby, and more.

More connection options. While REST focuses on request-response architecture, gRPC provides support for data streaming with event-driven architectures: server-side
streaming, client-side streaming, and bidirectional streaming.